# Why Isn't My Mob Grinder Working? (Minecraft Pocket Edition)

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I followed all the steps to make my mob grinder and the tutorial was in 1.15 (Mine was too), he said it can be done in all versions of Minecraft, I even double-checked it. I'm sure I had lit all of the caves in a 148 block radius. The inside of the grinder was completely dark. The roof was very well lit. No matter what I had done, it still didn't work.
 Here's the tutorial:

Comment: I'll be very thankful and happy if you can help!

Comment: It would be helpful if you would show us what you've build yourself, what are the steps you followed exactly, and what goes wrong exactly.

Comment: I followed all the steps correctly and didn't messed up. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I'm sure you did mess up, it's just not sure how. Most likely you built it like in the tutorial, on ground level, except in a normal survival world, not superflat. As result, mobs in caves fill up the mob cap and your spawner produces nothing. And the author of the tutorial should be shot for not mentioning it, and promoting this antiquated design (dating back to Alpha) that is an endless source of woe for all new Minecraft players because even when it works, it works very poorly.

Comment: You're right, but I'm sure I had lit all of the caves in a 148 blocks radius. Thanks for your tip! I aprreciate it!

Comment: Thank you all for your tips! I very appreciate it! Keep it on!

Comment: I'd recommend using spectator mode to diagnose. 1. Are mobs spawning? 2 Are they struggling against the current and refuse to drop? 3. How many caves have you missed? (because it's about impossible to find *all* using just Survival mode.)

Comment: It didn't work It's cheating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably did nothing wrong. There is a known bug/behavior since May 2017 that mobs do not despawn as they should in bedrock edition (https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-21856).

Today (17 March 2020) it [was reported](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-21856?focusedCommentId=648247&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-648247) that mob farms are working. On that note, it would be really helpful if someone could link to a savefile with mob farms built so more people (myself included) could readily test and confirm that this issue is finally resolved without having to build a test world from scratch.